# Creating a Half Triangle from a String

Tags: java, eclipse

I am creating a code that takes a string and converts it to a half triangle, such as the example below for the string "banana"

```
     a  
    na  
   ana  
  nana
 anana
banana
```

So far, all I have is this

```
public static void triangleWord (java.lang.String s)
{
    for(int i = s.length() - 1; i >=0; i--)
    {
        System.out.println(s.substring(0, i+1));
    }
}
```

Which only prints one line, which is the string. I have no idea where to go from here, any help would be appreciated

Comment: It runs fine for me, except the triangle is upside down: banana
banan
bana
ban
ba
b

Comment: 1. you should start from the latest character, on the firs loop this displays the full string. 
2. You are not displaying the white spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
public static void triangleWord (java.lang.String s) {
    for (int i=s.length()-1; i >= 0; --i) {
        String spaces = new String(new char[i]).replace("\0", " ");
        System.out.println(spaces + s.substring(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public static void triangleWord(String s) {
    String f = "%" + s.length() + "s%n";
    for(int i = s.length() - 1; i >=0; i--)
        System.out.printf(f, s.substring(i));
}
```